# How to configure npm, git and bower for Visual Studio behind a proxy

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, proxy, visual-studio-2017, bower

How to configure properly Visual studio tools to work behind a proxy ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## To configure proxy settings for npm package manager

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open a Visual Studio developer command window (Go to Start menu -> In folder Visual Studio XXXX -> Developer Command Prompt)
3. In the Visual Studio developer command window, type the following command:
   `npm config set proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`.
4. Then type this command: `npm config set https-proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`.
5. Open Visual Studio.

## To configure proxy settings for git

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open a Visual Studio developer command window (Go to Start menu -> In folder Visual Studio XXXX -> Developer Command Prompt)
3. In the Visual Studio developer command window, type the following command:
   `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`.
4. Type this command:`git config --global https.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`.
5. Open Visual Studio.

## To configure proxy settings for bower

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to the user directory (Type %UserProfile% in the explorer's path)
3. Create the file .bowerrc (Type ".bowerrc." as file name)
4. Write

   ```
   { 
     "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com", 
     "proxy": "http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080", 
     "https-proxy": "http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080"
   }
   ```
5. Save the file
6. Open Visual Studio.

**WARNING**: If you have specials characters in your proxy password, you must encode the proxy url.  Example:

- **username**: DOMAIN\user name
- **password**: P@$$w0rd
- **proxy server**: 10.80.0.0
- **proxy port**: 8080
- **PROXY URL** with authentification: **http://DOMAIN%5Cuser+name%3AP%40%24%24w0rd@10.80.0.0:8080**

Et Voilà :)